# Converting int16 to float in C

Tags: c, floating-point, int

How do i convert a 16 bit int to a floating point number?

I have a signed 16 bit variable which i'm told i need to display with an accuracy of 3 decimal places, so i presume this would involve a conversion to float?

I've tried the below which just copy's my 16 bits into a float but this doesn't seem right.

```
float myFloat = 0;
int16_t myInt = 0x3e00;
memcpy(&myFloat, &myInt, sizeof(int));
```

I've also read about the Half-precision floating-point format but am unsure how to handle this... if i need to.

I'm using GCC.

update:
The source of the data is a char array [2] which i get from an i2c interface. I then stitch this together into a signed int.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hm. Why is it `int16` initially at the first place at all? what does it represent?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. A 16-bit integer is an integer. It has no decimal places.

Comment: I suppose your requirement is slightly more articulated (unless they're asking a nonsense). Maybe you have a 16 bit signed value from an ADC which must be converted to a `float` according to the input physical range (which you do not show us) with 3 digits precision (or something like that). If you have range of `int16_t` and range of input value then...it's just a proportion.

Comment: Hi, the data is returned to me from an i2c interface as a char array [2] which i stitched together into a signed int.

Comment: So *why* did you "stitched together into a signed int"? What the datasheet of your sensor is telling you about the format of the data?

Comment: "i need to display with an accuracy of 3 decimal places, " --> If `myInt` had values like `0x3e00, 1, -1, 1002, -12345, -32768`, what output would be expected?

Comment: Am i correct to assume that the data is in the format MSB, LSB where the LSB represents the decimals after the point? In that case you can read in the data by creating a variable of type float and assign the MSB to it and add the LSB / 256 to it. If you want to use the data it is often beneficial to have that data in the correct format. Creating a function to convert the data to a char array will make testing easier.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a signed 16 bit variable which i'm told i need to display with
>   an accuracy of 3 decimal places

If someone told you the `integer` value can be displayed this way he/she should start from the C begginers course.

The only possibility is that the integer value has been scaled (multiplied). For example the value of 12.456 can be stored in the integer if multiplied by 1000. If this is the case:

```
float flv;
int intv = 12456;

flv = (float)intv / 1000.0f;
```

You can also print this scaled integer without convering to float

```
printf("%s%d.%03d\n", intv < 0 ? "-": "", abs(intv / 1000), abs(intv % 1000));
```

Comment: Better, yet consider `intv = -1`.  May need something like `printf("%s%d.%03d", "-"[intv >= 0], abs(intv / 1000), abs(intv % 1000));`